# Does the Atmel-ICE Debugger work on ATtiny MCUs?

Tags: avr, atmel, attiny, debugging, emulator

I've looked on the interwebtubes and could not find out if the [Atmel-ICE debugger](http://store.atmel.com/PartDetail.aspx?q=p:10500375;c:100112#tc:description) works with ATtiny MCUs.

In theory, since the debugger supports debugWire and SPI modes, it should, but the official page doesn't list them as supported devices and the internet doesn't seem to know.

I'd like to know for sure before I dish out the cash: my AVR Dragon self destructed and I need an upgrade.

Many thanks.

Comment: As an aside, the ICE cannot perform all the same functions as the Dragon, most notably HVPP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mine works OK with ATtiny AVRs.

AVR Studio will tell you which programmers and debuggers work with a particular chip, when you select it.

Comment: That's a good trick!  Thanks for sharing.  When you say that it works OK, does this mean that there are better alternatives?

Comment: The connector for the target cable is a bit flimsy and is easily damaged. The Dragon's cable connector is more robust.